# Как стилизовать часть страницы не используя классы в верстке?

Tags: html, css

Нужно часть страницы стилизовать без классов, как это делать и зачем вообще такое иногда требуется? На что тогда привязывать css стили?

Answer (score 2):

Можно подключить не только через класс, но и через идентификатор

```css
#IdStyleExample {
  background-color: #c8f2bd;
}
```

```html
<div id="IdStyleExample">уникальный, в отличии от класса</div>
```

[Можно почитать в дополнение](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/sposoby-dobavleniya-stiley-na-stranitsu)

Еще задают через body, как общий параметр на всю `html` страницу

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
  /* на всю страницу */
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
  /* на все заголовки 1 */
}

p {
  color: red;
  /* на все параграфы */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

например бывает проект большой, и искать все заголовки и вписывать им класс, можно пропустить, а так задать через сам тег, общий стиль

Answer (score 0):

Каждому элементу будь-то `div` или `p` *(или любой другой)*. Можно задать свойство `style`.

---

Пример.

```
<div style = "display: flex; align-items: center;">
   <p style = "padding: 10px;">TEST</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А, в этом смысле, понял.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно делаю по тегам.
Часто нужно при верстке страниц для CMS, когда конечный пользователь, не владеющий HTML, вводит текст и картинки.

Например:

```css
h2 {
    font: 20px "Gilroy-Extrabold",sans-serif;
    color: #455582;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h3 {
    font: 15px "Gilroy-Extrabold",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #455582;
}

p {
   font: 15px "Gilroy-Extrabold",sans-serif;
}

h4 {
    font: 14px/1.5 "Robotobold",sans-serif;
    color: #455582;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2>История АО&nbsp;«Ромашка»</h2>
          <h3>Добро пожаловать !</h3>
          <p>Мы&nbsp;— крупнейший поставщик. Мы супер!</p>
          <p>Мы&nbsp;— динамично развивающееся компания, ключевым направлением деятельности которой является надежное и&nbsp;качественное обеспечение.</p>
          <h4>Для достижения этой цели АО&nbsp;«Ромашка»:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Внедряет современные технологии;</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Сокращает потери и&nbsp;снижает затраты;</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>Мы все родные, друзья, знакомые или соседи, на&nbsp;жизни которых отражается качество нашей работы.</p>
          <p>Чтобы выполнять свою работу на&nbsp;достойном уроне, мы&nbsp;должны понимать друг друга, уважать друг друга, помогать друг другу. </p>
```